# Ember child state not available until the current runloop has finished

Tags: ember.js

I have the following child state definition:

```js
App.ChildState = Ember.State.create({
  enter: function(manager) {
     //do stuff
  },
  start: Ember.ViewState.create({
    view: App.LoadingView,
    enter: function(manager) {
      this._super(manager);

      // manager cannot find the child otherstate
      manager.transitionTo('otherstate.index');
    }
  }),
  otherstate: App.OtherState
```

The manager cannot find the child otherstate unless I wrap the call in Ember.run.next like this:

```
Ember.run.next(function(){
   manager.transitionTo('otherstate.index');
});
```

Can anyone let me know why this delay is necessary for the manager to be able to find this child state and transition to it?

Comment: it turned out to be a state nesting issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not proper design to have a state's enter method trigger a transition. You should use an action to do any conditional state transitioning.